# is dot always used as extension separator?

Tags: file, separator

Only interesting, is dot (".") always used for separate name from extension in the full file name or exits some system/locale ... where other symbols used?
Thanks.

Comment: That would depend on the operating system, any particular one in mind?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are looking for but files can have multiple dots in the filename.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, a filename starting with a dot is hidden, and usually a configuration file, like .bashrc.

You may have multiple dots like foo.txt.bak  and foo.tar.bz2.